# How to create a Typographic Map with Mapnik

Tags: python, mapnik

So i am trying to make a typographic map using mapnik. I want the street names along a particular street not to overlap, but I want an intersection between two streets to over lap. Currently[image] some streets don't have repeating labels. see attached image for whats happening. How do I accomplish this?

```
labelStyle = mapnik.Style()
text = mapnik.TextSymbolizer(mapnik.Expression("[FULL_NAME]"), "DejaVu Sans Book", 2,     mapnik.Color("#171717"))
text.label_placement = mapnik.label_placement.line
text.label_spacing = 2
text.force_odd_labels = True
text.min_distance = 0
#text.max_distance = len((mapnik.Expression("[FULL_NAME]"))
text.character_spacing = 1
text.minimum_path_length = 0
text.label_position_tolerance = 100
text.allow_overlap = 1
text.avoid_edges = 0
r.symbols.append(text)
#labelStyle.rules.append(r)
s.rules.append(r)
m.append_style('Text',s)
```

Comment: Maybe try to play with the min_scale max_scale denominators first to only show the appropriate street names (like avenues above a certain level etc)? https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/MinScaleDenominator